# Determining the Existence of Maximum and Minimum Values for a Function over a Given Subset

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Given the subsets $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and mappings $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$, determine whether $\max(M, f)$ and $\min(M, f)$ exist and provide your justifications.$M = \{(x, y)^{t} \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 \leq x^2 + y^4 \leq 2\}$, $f(x, y) = e^{xy} - \cos(\sin(x^2))$

$\textbf{Solution:}$
To determine the existence of $\max(M, f)$ and $\min(M, f)$, we need to analyze the function $f$ over the subset $M$.

First, let's consider the lower bound of $f$ over $M$. Since $f$ is continuous and $M$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, by the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ attains its minimum value over $M$. Therefore, $\min(M, f)$ exists.

Next, we consider the upper bound of $f$ over $M$. We observe that $f(x, y)$ is unbounded as $(x, y)$ approaches the boundary of $M$. Specifically, as $x^2 + y^4$ approaches $1$ or $2$, the value of $f(x, y)$ increases without bound. Therefore, $\max(M, f)$ does not exist.

Is my solution detailed enough?

Comment: Did you mean $M\subset \mathbb R^2$ instead of $M\subset \mathbb R$? Your $f$ appears to be a function of two real variables. Also, is your formula for $f$ correct? As written, your $f$ is continuous on then whole plane, so it is bounded on any compact set (specifically, it is bounded on $M$).

Comment: (continued) ... note the region $M$ looks like a squished annulus. It is certainly a closed and bounded region.

Comment: I edited the text and this is exactly my exercise

Comment: Why do you think $f$ becomes unbounded as $x^2 + y^4$ approaches $1$ or $2$? It does not. In fact, $|f(x,y)| < e^4+1$ on $M$ (because $e^{xy} <e^{2\cdot 2}$ since $M\subset [-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ and $\cos(\cdot) \leq 1$).

Comment: And why do you write $(x,y)^t$? presumably $x\in \mathbb R$ and $y\in\mathbb R$, so $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: You can apply your argument for $\min\limits_M f$ to deduce the same thing about the maximum, since $\max\limits_M f = -\min\limits_M(-f)$.

Comment: Could you eventually formulize your solution as an answer? I would really appreciate it

Comment: With the hints and observations I have given in comments, you should be able to write an answer yourself. Please do that.